# Finding Height and Base of a Triangle

Tags: geometry

This is a question I got off of one of my previous math tests, and I don't even know where to start with solving it.

The height of a triangle is 4 times its base. If the area of the triangle is 160 square meters, find its base and height. Write your answers in simplest radical form.

Comment: what formulas for area do you know?

Answer (score 3):

$A = \frac 12 b\cdot h = 160\tag{1}$

$h =4\cdot b\tag{2}$

So, $$A = \frac 12 b(4b) = 2b^2 = 160$$

Solve for $b$ (base). Then use this to compute $h = 4b$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}b(4b)\neq 48b^2$

Comment: @calculus. I had written `\frac 12 b(4b)` and saw the `12`...but forgot it was preceded by `\frac`!

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: Thank you for saying something, @calculus.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot h\cdot b=160$

Because of $h=4b$ it is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4b\cdot b=160$

Just solve the equation.

greetings,

calculus

Answer (score 0):

Please remember the triangle area formula
$$A = \frac{h*b}{2}$$
then note, that 
$$h=4b$$
So substitute the height and solve for base, then multiply by 4 for height.